# Will Meteor deploy run modules in node_modules via node?

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, npm, mqtt

I have build an app using meteor. I have placed mosca node module inside node_modules folder as server.js. On local machine i used to run meteor then run node server.js on another terminal.

So when i deploy my app to meteor servers, will node run automatically or i have to set something?

Also what will be host address for mosca in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this method works deploying to Meteor.com (if thats what you mean by meteor servers), you have a couple of options for adding npm packages though:

**1) Use the [meteorhacks npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) package for Meteor**

`meteor add meteorhacks:npm`

create a file called `packages.json`

```
{
  "mosca": "1.0.2"
}
```

Then in your server side code you do:

```
var Mosca = Meteor.npmRequire('mosca');
mosca = new Mosca();
```

and voila mosca should be usable

**2) Try the [new npm functionality](https://medium.com/@borellvi/meteor-meets-npm-a5cc48d90abe#.rss9otenh) in Meteor 1.3 + (note: this is currently in beta at the moment)** (you will need to specify the --release tag in your deploy)

Comment: I worked with minor change. No need to create object. Directly use Mosca